# Drop down menu to display content below it once a list item is selected, best way to do it?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I need to create a simple dropdown menu which combined with a text box (example 100px below it) should show the info related to that choice when selected. I'm thinking about displaying the info in simple text, then customize it with CSS. To achieve this result should i create different classes/variables in Javascript or is there a way to do that just with HTML and CSS? (Or is there a better way to do this?) I have no idea even how to start this. I suppose i'll have to study a lot of Javascript to do this in the end, but if you are aware of any good resources, please, even a link to a nice tutorial would be very much appreciated!

My knowledge of Javascript is basic if not slightly over zero.

Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Refer to `onchange` event of `<select>` tag and JS functions. Refer this link for example [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange)

Comment: Brilliant @RaghavaRudrakanthPV, simple yet effective! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what I got from question correct me if I understood something else.

You can write HTML like

```
<select id="opt">
    <option> NO 1</option>
    <option> NO 2</option>
    <option> NO 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="info" value="No1 info"/>
```

And using jquery you can get the value what user selected and then according to that display the information.

```
$("#opt").change(function(){
    var choice=$(this).val();
   $("#info").val(info(choice));
})
 var info=function(choice){
     var iz ;
     switch(choice){
     case "NO 1":iz="No1 info";
     break;
     case "NO 2":iz="No2 info"
     break;
     case "NO 3":iz="No3 info"
     break;
     }
      return(iz);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create it fast, despite understanding what is really going on, you should try to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), here is a link for an example of [what you want to do](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns).

Otherwise, you can find multiple tutorials online that would explain how to achieve something like this using pure css or javascript ([example](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/)).